# Not able to produce table based on conditional select

Tags: select, condition

I would like to achieve something that probably ends up in some kind of conditional select (MS SQL) but I do not know how to.

I have tried to simplified my problem to the description below:

I have 3 tables: 1 containing Articles (Art_number, Art_description and Productgroup), the second with Customers (Cust_number and Cust_name) and a third table containing discount information (Cust_number, Productgroup and Discount_percentage)

Table: Articles

```
001,fork,cutlery
002,knife,cutlery
003,plate,tableware
004,cup,tableware
```

Table: Customer

```
1234,smith
5678,jones
```

Table: Discounts

```
1234,cutlery,0.9
1234,tableware,0.8
5678,cutlery,0.75
5678,tableware,0.7
```

My questions is about the relation with a 4th table that contains some (not all!) alternative (customer related) article numbers named Cross_Ref that links the first two tables by containing a article number and a customernumber (Art_number, Alt_Art_Nr and Customer_Nr)

Table: Cross_Ref

```
002,1002,1234
002,92002,5678
004,1004,1234
004,92004,5678
```

I would like to produce a table that shows the article numbers in the first column, 
Article description in the second column.
The alternative article numbers in the third, column (if available, otherwise empty) and the Customer name in 4th column

It should look like this with the information above:

```
001,fork,,smith
001,fork,,jones
002,knife,1002,smith
002,knife,92002,jones
003,plate,,smith
003,plate,,jones
004,cup,1004,smith
004,cup,92004,jones
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT Art_number, Art_description, Alt_Art_Nr, Cust_name
FROM Articles,
Customer,
Cross_Ref
WHERE Articles.Art_number = Cross_Ref.Art_number 
and Customer.Cust_number = Cross_Ref.Customer_Nr
and Customer.Cust_number = Discounts.Cust_number
and Articles.Productgroup = Discounts.Productgroup
```

This only shows me those lines that indeed have an alternative article number, but do not show the articles that do not have a reference mentioned in the Cross_Ref table.

In principle it is a combination of 4 tables that are connected fully by 3 tables, but the 4th table only contains a number of the articles (that have a alternative number) and thereby resulting in only those articlenumbers in the query result, while I would like to see all the article numbers and empty (NULL) fields, if there is no result.

Can anybody show me an example how to archive this?

Comment: Your 4th snippet ("should look like this") shows in the first line a row that I can't make sense of. How did the fork article become linked to the Smith record?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for your reply. I see I have simplified my questions to far. The Customer table is also linked to the Article table with another table that contains information about the prices for each article in relation to each customer. So the information is linked via that table also. However the price table contains a reference for all article numbers (for each customer) and didn't gave me a headache like this issue :-)

Comment: Well, add that 4th table in your question! You don't suppose others have a crystal ball?

Comment: @ypercube, Sorry I didn't realize I simplified my example too far. I have added information of the 4th table. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I've noticed there was a answer explaining a left join, but cant find it anymore?

Comment: It was deleted by the poster.

Comment: @Herbiek I can't see the `Discounts.Productgroup` column in the table's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output, I think you need a query of the type:

```
FROM 
    (Base)
  LEFT JOIN
    Cross_Ref
      ON  (Base columns) = (Cross_Ref columns)
```

---

Without some more information for the `Discount` table, we can't be sure but the `(Base)` should probably be either (the cartesian product of the two tables):

```
    Articles CROSS JOIN Customers
```

or (a join using another intermediate table, i.e.):

```
    Articles 
    JOIN Discount (ON ...) 
    JOIN Customers (ON ...)
```

---

So, the final query should be similar to either:

```
SELECT 
    a.Art_number, a.Art_description, ref.Alt_Art_Nr, c.Cust_name
FROM
    Articles AS a CROSS JOIN Customers AS c
  LEFT JOIN
    Cross_Ref AS ref
      ON  a.Art_number = ref.Art_number 
      AND c.Cust_number = ref.Customer_Nr ;
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    a.Art_number, a.Art_description, ref.Alt_Art_Nr, c.Cust_name
FROM
    Articles AS a
  JOIN 
    Discount AS d ON a.Productgroup = d.Productgroup
  JOIN 
    Customers AS c ON c.Cust_number = d.Cust_number
  LEFT JOIN
    Cross_Ref AS ref
      ON  a.Art_number = ref.Art_number 
      AND c.Cust_number = ref.Customer_Nr ;
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube, the second query brought me to the correct solution, especially the AND in the query was an eyeopener. As I see the solution, it looks simple and wondered why I couldn't find this solution myself :S

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking at needing an OUTER JOIN instead of the implied INNER JOINs that you're using. e.g. suppose

```
   Table 1 Employee (Empl_number, Empl_Name)
   001, Paul
   002, John
   003, Fred

   Table 2 EmployeeRoles (Role_ID, Role_Desc)
   100, Manager
   200, Clerk
   300, KeyHolder

   Table 3 RoleLink (ID, Empl_number, Role_ID
   1, 001, 100
   2, 001, 300
   3, 002, 200
```

Then to get a list of all employees and their roles you would use

```
   SELECT e.empl_number, e.empl_name, ISNULL(r.role_desc, 'No role')
   FROM EMPLOYEE e
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLELINK l on e.empl_number = l.empl_number
   LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEEROLES r on l.role_id = r.role_id
```

Would give

```
   001, Paul, Manager
   001, Paul, Keyholder
   002, John, No role
   003, Fred, Clerk
```

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, however after editing my initial question, I now realize that my issue involves 4 tables that all are connected. Only 1 table (Cross_Ref) doesn't have a full list of items so I have to work with LEFT OUTER JOIN, otherwise I end up with only those items related with the items in that table. However I still cant get my head around a correct query describing the relation with JOIN with 4 tables (in a circle?). Can you give me such an example?